# remove configuration providers for integration tests in .NET 6

Tags: dependency-injection, integration-testing, .net-6.0, configurationmanager

I currently have a web app on .NET 6 with integration tests using `WebApplicationFactory`.
Here is a simplified version of my Program.cs file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;
var configuration = builder.Configuration;

services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            var configs = configuration.GetRequiredSection("authOptions");
            // using configs here
        });
```

For most services I need to mock, I can remove them from the service descriptor. However, this would not work for services like adding authentication from what I have seen. Basically, I am looking for a way to mock the configurations for integration testing.
The `AddJwtBearer` also has no access to the `IServiceProvider` and thus cannot use the injectable `IConfiguration`. I would like to account for all such features that need to use the configuration from `builder.Configuration`.

I am trying something like this:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory: WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configBuilder =>
        {
             // remove all configs or at least user secrets from config builder
             // add mocked configurations
        });
    }

}
```

I would like to **remove** the configuration so as to make sure in future if I add a configuration I forget to mock, the integration test would throw an exception instead of using the user secrets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following approach if you would like to clear any existing default configuration providers and then add your custom configuration.

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory: WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configBuilder =>
        {
            //clears all the default configuration providers
            configBuilder.Sources.Clear();
            //Add your custom configuration from Json file or memory
        });
    }
}
```

You can find more examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration-providers#json-configuration-provider).

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work because the `Program` class starts with `WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` which creates a new builder that never goes anywhere near the `WebApplicationFactory`.

Comment: @RichardBarraclough I noticed, how to solve this ?