# GetRequiredSection and intergration tests

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When using GetRequiredSecion in an ASP Net 6 app, i run into an issue where GetRequiredSection runs before the call to AddInMemoryCollection in my test, resulting in an exception:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure app settings
var mySettingSection = builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("MySettings");
var mySettingValue = mySettingSection["MyKey"];

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapGet("/", (Func<string>)(() => $"Hello, your setting value is: {mySettingValue}"));

app.Run();
```

Integration test where I attempt to substitute the configuration:

```
namespace SimpleApp.Tests
{
    public class IntegrationTests : IClassFixture<WebApplicationFactory<Program>>
    {
        private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;

        public IntegrationTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
        {
            _factory = factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
                {
                    config.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "MySettings:MyKey", "Value from integration test" }
                    });
                });
            });
        }

        [Fact]
        public async Task GetHomePage_ShouldReturnCustomSettingValue()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.CreateClient();

            // Act
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("/");

            // Assert
            Assert.Contains("Value from integration test", response);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get around this issue without replacing GetRequiredSection with GetSection?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to override the configuration and also use custom settings for integration tests.

```
IConfigurationRoot configurationRoot = new ConfigurationBuilder()
.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.AddJsonFile("appsettings.IntegrationTests.json").Build();

builder.UseConfiguration((IConfiguration) configurationRoot);
```

Alternatively, you can try my proposed solution from this post - [remove configuration providers for integration tests in .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73264490/remove-configuration-providers-for-integration-tests-in-net-6/73266678#73266678)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are not 100% free about your choice of code. So let try locally first : **when tested locally it work fine**. GetRequiredSection is not problematic there.

When `appsettings.IntegrationTests.json` have the key section **OR** the set up of the key using `AddInMemoryCollection`, both work fine. Please note that the use of two method at the same time will create hazardous behavior (what key is used ? from the json file or the method AppInMeMoryCollection ?).

You don't mention exactly what the error is. Please check that you don't have a key set up in app setting file and using AppInMeMoryCollection.

When I make it work on my side, I have to face a very annoying configuration issue :

- check into your import of the test project that you don't have `using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestHost;`, it have a definition of Program file that would get in conflict with the Program class of your project.

Let me know and take care.

---

*Additional note*

For this type of integration test, I would suggest to use external tools rather than unit test lib.

Because you test the integration of many components from an external point of view (end point + code + database), you should remove as much as possible all those configuration complexity by using end point testing. In addition, method already heavily used/tested (like `GetRequiredSection`) are not worth to test, I suppose microsoft run some test on it. But that great to test the integration of all those components !

For example, postman have a tab "test" where you can set up test within minutes and make it easier, avoiding all those vs+c#+xunit+??? configuration trouble. Another alternative could be the use of the `.http` file for testing. Sound promising but I never use it yet.